# Netsuite transform salesorder to cash sale error

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

ive got a perculiar issue when trying to transform a salesorder to a cash sale and cant find any material to suggest why the message is appearing.

```
You have an invalid sales order 1415 or the order is already closed.
```

pretty ordinary code,

```
function scratch(request,response)
{
    var record = nlapiLoadRecord('salesorder','1415');
    var transform = nlapiTransformRecord('salesorder','1415','cashsale');
    nlapiSubmitRecord(transform,true,true);
}
```

The thing I cant seem to work out, is where the transaction is being set as closed?

Ive tred to change the sales order form to a cash sale form, with no difference,
Ive tried to change the paymentmethod to cash. no difference either.

Is there something Im doing to the sales order prior to creating the transformation, or is there something in the creation of the original sales order record causing this issue?

thanks in advance

Comment: What is the status of the sales order?

Comment: pending fulfillment is what is indicated when i go to edit it

Comment: You either need to fulfill the SO or enable bill before fulfill

Answer (score 3):

Edit the standard SalesOrder form and in the fields under Columns, turn on Closed.  This will add the closed column on the SalesOrder.  It sounds like you might have closed lines.

One way to test transforming is to bill the SalesOrder in the UI.  If the bill button isn't available than you usually can't even script the transform.

Comment: Another item to check is the payment method.  The payment method must match the type of transform you are trying to do (invoice/cashsale).